# MySQL UPDATE and CASE

Tags: mysql, sql-update, case

New to MySQL (coming from Oracle), and I have this UPDATE :

```
UPDATE the_table
SET the_col = 'the_value',
    the_col2 = CASE WHEN the_col = 'the_value' THEN 'x' ELSE 'y' END
WHERE a = 1;
```

The idea is to set the_col2 to 'x' if the_col is set to 'the_value', otherwise set it to 'y'.

What I am seeing is the_col being updated fine, but the_col2.

I am not getting an error reported so I am assuming the syntax/usage is OK.

It is as if the "SET the_col = 'the_value'" sets the value so that when referenced in the CASE it has the new value. I think this is unlikely, but this seems to be what is happening.

What I want to do is test the column's value pre-update.

Comment: What if you reverse the order of the SETs?

Comment: *The idea is to set the_col2 to 'x' if the_col is set to 'the_value'* But this is the case for all records in your query

Comment: @OP: The syntax is correct. Value will be pre-set and should work. Which version are your working with?

Comment: Thanks all, wasn't able to get this working, so resorted to using a trigger, which in itself took me ages on account of phpMyAdmin being silly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the_col has the new value when you do the set the_col2 case...

But one way to find out - run the update twice, doing the_col, then the_col2. Compare answers (you'll have to - should - make a temporary table to be safe. Note: to create a temporary test table (since you're new to MySQL and it might be different), a) run DESCRIBE your_table; b) use the values in that to CREATE TABLE temp_table; c) create a subquery to read out all the rows in your_table and insert them into temp_table - e.g. INSERT into temp_table values (select * from your table). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Just one of those strange things. In the end I resorted to creating a trigger to deal with this.